# Find basis of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{-3})$ over the field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}\omega)$.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Splitting field for the polynomial $\ x^3-2$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{-3})$. Now roots of the above polynomial are $\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{2}\omega, \sqrt[3]{2}{\omega}^2$
Since they are the roots of polynomial we have 
$\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}\omega)$ as vector space over $\mathbb Q$. 
This implies that degree of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{-3})$ over 
$\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}\omega)$ is 2. Then what will be its basis which should contain 2 elements?
Also, does any of the $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\sqrt{-3}$ belong to field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}\omega)$?

Edit: By contradiction I concluded that $\sqrt{-3} \notin \mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}\omega)$.

Comment: Please fix the formatting, see  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The generator/basis of the quadratic extension $\mathbb{ Q(\sqrt[3]{2}\omega,\sqrt{-3})/Q(\sqrt[3]{2}\omega})$ is supposedly obvious

Comment: Note that $\omega=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2}$.

Comment: Looks good now (+1). Hint: if the field $\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2\omega)$ contained either $\sqrt{-3}$ or $\root3\of2$ it would contain the splitting field. Do you see why?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think because if any one if them is contained in $\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2\omega)$ then by doing some multiplication and division in field we can prove it will contain all 3 roots of that polynomial. Hence, polynomial will split in this field. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. If you adjoin any two roots you get the the third free of charge (because their sum is rational). Adjoining one of the roots and either $\omega$ or $\sqrt{-3}$ will give you the splitting field because then you have a degree six extension.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks I understood. But, can you give me basis for splitting field over $\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2\omega)$.

Comment: All of $\omega$, $\sqrt{-3}$ and $\root3\of2$ are quadratic algebraic over $K=\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2\omega)$. There any one of $\{1,\omega\}$, $\{1,\sqrt{-3}\}$ or $\{1,\root3\of2\}$ are bases for $L/K$, $L=\Bbb{Q}(\omega,\root3\of2)$ the splitting field. Pick one!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you so much. I got it.